# React: Calling functions, why the first one works and not the second one?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, func

Maybe this is a silly question but I want to know why is it so that...

```
const isDisabled = () => 
  // condition check
```

This works:

```
<button
  type="button"
  disabled={this.isDisabled()}
>
  Let Me In
</button>
```

but this does not work:

```
<button
   type="button"
   disabled={this.isDisabled}
>
  Let Me In
</button>
```

Comment: Because second one returns function, and attr disabled need boolean

Comment: Use `React.useState` instead

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the first example with `this.isDisabled()` you call the function.
In the second example with `this.isDisabled` you pass the function reference without call.

Try to `console.log()` them both to see the difference.
The second one works just like variable. For example:

```
var myFunction = this.isDisabled; // I've put the reference to myFunction
myFunction(); // now I've called isDisabled()
```

Answer (score 0):

Because `disabled` needs to be a boolean:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/button#attr-disabled

Answer (score 0):

When you add parenthesis like this.isDisabled(), the function is executed and the return value is assigned to the disabled attribute of the button.
When you are just say `disabled = this.isDisabled`, you are just passing a reference of the function and hence the value is not evaluated.

Also remember that, disable attribute on a button is a boolean value. So check on the value that you return from the function.